# Audio compatibility between iOS and Flash player

Tags: ios, objective-c, actionscript-3, flash, audio

I have been given a task to implement sending and receiving audio between an iOS device and a flash player on the web. The issue that em facing is the format of the audio file that i could send from the iOS device, receive on the web flash player and play it there. And similarly vice versa.

Up till now i have been able to save audio file from the iOS device in `m4a` format and been able to send it across but not able to play it on the flash player. Similarly i've recorded the audio using flash player in `mp3` format and send it from there but not able to play here.

Thank you in advance and for reading the whole question.

Comment: Are you using native objective C on the mobile and as3 flash on the web?

Comment: Yes.. exactly thats what em using

Comment: Since Flash is not supporting by iPhone I think you have to use any thirdparty tool.

Comment: yes i have gotten to this point till now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flash can play mp3 or [rawdata](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/SampleDataEvent.html)

mp3 format on the recorder side can be encoded by using http://lame.sourceforge.net/ however there are legal limitation there since the mp3 encoding is patent. For most projects this solution will not work.

rawdata is the way to go here , I don't know the ios supported sound formats well but what I would look for is a way to convert them to raw-data, and read them directly with the SampleDataEvent or use something with more oprions such as https://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/  or https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3

Sorry I don't have the full answer here but if you can figure out a way to get the rawdata from one of the iOS supported formats you're 90% there.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed advice.. iOS can support m4a, aac, wav, caf formats.. all of them could be converted in to raw format as in binary data.. then i guess sending it over to flash and then encoding it in any format should be able to do the trick...

Comment: then .wav is the way to go, these are your 2 options :  simple lightweight util - https://code.google.com/p/as3wavsound/   ,   large library but better quality sound and lots of cool features (if u need)   https://github.com/maxl0rd/standingwave3

Comment: no need to convert to raw data , just send the .wav file to the flash player and deal with it with 1 of the 2 options in the comment above